# How to ignore an example when running tests with cargo?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'm making a proc_macro crate where I have 2 examples in the directory examples/.

When I run `cargo test`, the 2 examples are compiled but one of the examples is failing on purpose and it prevents the test from running. I want to make an example that fails to compile to show the user how it works.

[According to the doc](https://rurust.github.io/cargo-docs-ru/manifest.html#examples) this behavior is intended:

> They must compile as executables (with a main() function) and load in the library by using `extern crate <library-name>`. They are compiled when you run your tests to protect them from bitrotting.

This is fine but how can I disable the compilation for my failing example?

Answer (score 5):

I found it!

You can disable the automatic discovery of examples by adding `autoexamples = false` to `[package]`

Then you can enumerate all the examples yourself in the following way:

```
[package]
...
autoexamples = false

[[example]]
name = "basic"
path = "examples/basic.rs"
```

Comment: Ah wait no... I can't build the example anymore... bad answer